# Integrate separate java applications as modules of a single application

Tags: java, spring-boot, modular-design

I have some separate java applications, developed for performing different tasks. Now I want to integrate these applications as a single application. I want to develop a core for the integrated application, such that anyone can add some modules to it for different tasks without the need to change the core application. The modules have no dependency on each other but all of them use depend on the core module. I prefer to use the spring-boot framework and the Maven build tool. 
Can anyone guide me by an appropriate tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

You could make yourself familiar with **maven submodules**. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html